# What is a word for someone who always has to be thinking something or messing with something?

Tags: word-request

This has been bothering me lately and I need to know. So for me if I'm not thinking something I'm messing with something(like a piece of paper in my hands), and if I'm not doing that I'm thinking(making up stories in my head). I always have to be doing something, I can't just do nothing. What's the word for that?(If their is a word)

Comment: Can you provide a few more details and possibly an example sentence showing how you would use this word?

Comment: Ok. Um.. So for me if I'm not thinking something I'm messing with something(like a piece of paper in my hands), and if I'm not doing that I'm thinking(making up stories in my head). I always have to be doing something, I can't just do nothing. What's the word for that?(If their is a word)

Comment: They are a *fidgeter* or *tinkerer* (if they are always curious).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider *restless* and *fidgety*:

> - [restless](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/restless)
>
>   1. characterized by or showing inability to remain at rest:
>        *a restless mood.*
>   2. unquiet or uneasy, as a person, the mind, or the heart.
>   3. never at rest; perpetually agitated or in motion:
>        *the restless sea.*
>   4. without rest; without restful sleep:
>        *a restless night.*
>   5. unceasingly active; averse to quiet or inaction, as persons:
>        *a restless crowd.*
>
>   (Dictionary.com)
> - [fidgety](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/fidgety)
>     Someone who is fidgety keeps fidgeting, for example, because they are nervous or bored.
>     (Collins)

Neither exactly suggests that you're thinking a lot. You may need to specify that.

Comment: Good choices!  Additionally, people who are restless or fidgety have a tendency to 'fiddle' with things and 'daydream'.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the word you are looking for.

> Attention-Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder (ADHD) or "Hyperactivity"

Reference: https://www.understood.org/en/learning-attention-issues/child-learning-disabilities/hyperactivity-impulsivity/understanding-your-childs-trouble-with-hyperactivity